# PSAKE powershell & execute task not running

Tags: powershell, build, psake

Trying to get a PSAKE script to work.  Its seems that tasks are not executing the functions within them?

I have 2 files

```
-- default.ps1 --
Import-Module "C:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\Build\BuildScripts\include.ps1"
Import-Module "C:\Software\PSAKE\JamesKovacs-psake-b0094de\psake.psm1"
Invoke-psake "C:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\Build\BuildScripts\build.ps1"
remove-module psake


-- build.ps1 --
$framework = '4.0'

properties {
    $root_dir = 'c:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\'
    $integration_deploy_dir = '\\Server025\Phoenix_IntegrationTests\'
    $build_scripts_dir = '$root_dir\Build\BuildScripts'
    $test_dir =  Join-Path $root_dir '\Tests\Core.UnitTests\bin\Debug'
    $dll = Join-Path $test_dir 'Phoenix.Core.UnitTests.dll'
} 


task default -depends Test

task MsBuild {  exec { msbuild /version }}

task Test -depends Deploy
{
    Write-Host "Start task Test"
Add-PSSnapIn Gallio
Write-Host "TEST --  $dll" 
Test-Gallio $test_dir Release x64 $dll "Core.UnitTests"     ## FYI - call to include func
Write-Host "End task Test"
}

task Deploy
{
Write-Host "Start task deploy"
Write-Host "Deploying to integration server"
copy $root_dir"\Sites" $integration_deploy_dir -Recurse -Force
Write-Host "End task deploy"    
}
```

At the moment it just seems to 'print out' the stuff listed within tasks without actually doing anything.  What am I missing?  Thanks

Sorry forgot to mention I really just want to get the COPY method working first -- thx

---

Thanks for the help - Ive made all your suggestions and still no luck.

If I put the code 'inline' rather that in PSAKE tasks the code runs fine.

I now have this

```
-- default.ps1
Import-Module C:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\Build\BuildScripts\include.ps1
Import-Module C:\Software\PSAKE\JamesKovacs-psake-b0094de\psake.psm1
Invoke-psake C:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\Build\BuildScripts\build.ps1
remove-module psake
```

-- build.ps1
    $framework = '4.0'

```
properties {
$root_dir = 'c:\dev\Phoenix\trunk'
$sites_dir = 'c:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\sites'
$integration_deploy_dir = '\\Vsydnweb025\Phoenix_IntegrationTests\'
$build_scripts_dir = "$root_dir\Build\BuildScripts"
}

task default -depends Deploy

task Deploy
{
Write-Host 'Start task deploy'
Write-Host 'Deploying to integration server'
copy $sites_dir $integration_deploy_dir -Recurse -Force
Write-Host 'End task deploy'
get-childitem $integration_deploy_dir -include *.svclog -recurse | foreach ($_)  {remove-item $_.fullname}
}
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
Write-Host 'Start task deploy'
Write-Host 'Deploying to integration server'
copy $sites_dir $integration_deploy_dir -Recurse -Force
Write-Host 'End task deploy'
get-childitem $integration_deploy_dir -include *.svclog -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}


Build Succeeded!

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Build Time Report
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Name   Duration        
----   --------        
Deploy 00:00:00.0006013
Total: 00:00:02.5335350
```

So it seems the functions within the task are just being printed out.

The copy function did not run - nor the Piped .SvcLog file delete

Ie on the screen I would expect

'Start task deploy'

instead of

Write-Host 'Start task deploy'

Ill keep trying to get it to work.

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Well I'm guessing the problem is PSAKE specific so I'm not going to be much use; I hesitate to provide this link but it's all I can find and may be of some use to you: http://www.pseale.com/blog/StealIdeasFromThesePsakeScripts.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had this answered in the google group

The beginning "{" needs to be on the same line as the "task" function since
it's a scriptblock that is being passed as a parameter to the "task"
function.  PS is interpreting your code as 2 statements instead of 1
statement.

Answer (score 1):

I've not done anything with PSAKE but with regards to Powershell, the following needs 'fixing':

```
$root_dir = 'c:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\'
```

Remove the trailing '\' as when you concatenate this variable with other strings (which begin with '\') you will end up with a double '\'.

Also:

```
$build_scripts_dir = '$root_dir\Build\BuildScripts'
```

This should have double quotes to ensure the variable is expanded correctly:

```
$build_scripts_dir = "$root_dir\Build\BuildScripts"
```

Maybe correct these and see if you get any more meaningful errors?

I suspect you will also need to remove the double quotes from around your script/module calls:

```
Import-Module C:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\Build\BuildScripts\include.ps1
Import-Module C:\Software\PSAKE\JamesKovacs-psake-b0094de\psake.psm1
Invoke-psake C:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\Build\BuildScripts\build.ps1
remove-module psake
```

...and see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx#EEAA) for a good run-down on how to call scripts from within scripts.  The double quotes you're using turns the call into a string (which won't execute).  If you need to use double quotes (i.e. your path includes spaces) then you need to preface the path with the call operator '&':

```
& "C:\dev\Phoenix\trunk\Build\BuildScripts\build.ps1"
```

Obviously, you don't need to do this as your path has no spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Made the changes you suggested.  It still is not actually running the tasks - it prints out whats inside them but does not action them?

Comment: I suspect the problem is your double quotes - try removing them from the default script, answer edited to include this.

Comment: Using `join-path` is a better solution to deal with the extra ``\``. It ensures that the final path doesn't have duplicates separators like that but doesn't require them to be there, either. Making a rule or assumption about the presence or absence of a trailing slash in a path is *never* a good idea; it always results in issues one way or the other in my experience.